# issue using dataset with data analysis project

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am doing a project on this dataset- https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/die9origephit/fifa-world-cup-2022-complete-dataset/code. The dataset is about the fifa 2022 world cup. For the project, I want to compare the performance of the United States to the winners of the competition, Argentina, as well as the rest of the teams in the competition. However, I'm having issues. The columns team1 and team2 correspond to the home team being team1 and away team being team2. In addition, im trying to compare the average possession for the competition that the US had to argentina's and then to the rest of the teams. The issue is possessionteam1 and possessionteam2 dont add up to 100%, as there is another column called possession in contest which accounts for the time that neither team had possession of the ball. if i want to make a bar chart with three different bars(one bar for the united states average possession throughout, one for argentina's average, then one for the rest of the teams' average)how would i do that with the limitations and things i just said?

I already tried different coding methods and tried to create a new column called total possession so it would be out of 100% but it was still giving me issues and not showing what i need

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.